# wait stopping typing convert from Function.Prototype to jQuery

Tags: jquery, prototype, wait, function-prototypes

I have a wait function in Prototype with which I can delay the execution of a function around time.
Sample:

```html
var doSomting = function(arg 1, arg2, ...){
   ...
}.wait(500);
```

The wait - Functions Code in Prototype is:

```html
Function.prototype.wait = function(time){
 var fn = this;
 var timeout = null;
 return function(){
  var inst = this;
  var args = arguments;
  $clear(timeout);
  timeout = window.setTimeout( function(){
   var ret = fn.apply(inst,args);
   }, time);
 };
};
```

I would like to have the same Methode `waitSpecial(time)` in jQuery (wait is taken in jQuery, so `waitSpecial()`)

I cannot convert the function. 
It is very helpful for me to convert.

Comment: what is your use case in jQuery? The api already has several methods you could probably use

Comment: the same as in Prototype to 
sluggish delay functions with arguments in the hole application

Comment: well that doesn't help much when not familiar with Prototype library. Look into using `queue()` and `delay()` that are built in

Comment: I want to replace Prototype with jQuery throughout the application. All other functions work. This is the last function to replace.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```html
Function.prototype.wait = function(time){
 var fn = this;
 var timeout = null;
 return function(){
  var inst = this;
  var args = arguments;
  clearTimeout(timeout);
  timeout = window.setTimeout( function(){
   var ret = fn.apply(inst,args);
   }, time);
 };
};
```

It works with jQuery fine